How to pipe stdin into Neovim?
I'm trying to pipe the output of an ansible-inventory command into Neovim. This works with Vim but when I try to do the equivalent with Neovim, the buffer is not correctly populated, meaning the buffer that should be populated is completely empty when Neovim opens.
Command that does not work:
ansible-inventory -i inventories/staging --list | nvim

Command that does work:
ansible-inventory -i inventories/staging --list | vi -

How do I do this? For example,
echo "hello" | nvim

does work, but the command I'm trying to use does not?
I also tried nvim -, no luck.

Welcome to Vim :-). Unfortunately I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe could you give us more information about. The operating system (Windows 10, macOS X, Linux). 2. The version of Neovim that you are using?

I'm running on a M2 MacOS, I'm using the latest Neovim (v0.10.0). For clarity, for example grepping and piping that to nvim works, but for some reason the ansible-inventory command does not. I've also tried to cat the command instead of passing it into nvim and it prints stuff. When piping it to nvim the buffer is empty.

Thanks for the clarifications. I don't have access to a Mac I'm not sure how to help. I would check that ansible log to the standard output and not to the standard error (although on Windows Vim only listen to the standard output making this hypothesis weak :-) )
